# Invalid Websockets frame error while using react-router-dom. I am not using websockets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, react-router, react-router-dom

So I'm having a weird issue that I can't seem to find the answer to on google or with any deeper digging. I am **not** using websockets in my React project.  However, I am using react-router-dom and when I go to my '/' link from another page I get this error and it crashes my app.  Anyone have any insight on what this is? Thanks guys.

My route just looks like this  `<Route exact path="/" component={Landing}/>`inside the Switch and Router components.  Typical stuff.

```
    RangeError: Invalid WebSocket frame: invalid status code 22373
    at Receiver.controlMessage (/home/chuckyp/Desktop/datingapp/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:449:18)
    at Receiver.getData (/home/chuckyp/Desktop/datingapp/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:335:42)
    at Receiver.startLoop (/home/chuckyp/Desktop/datingapp/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:138:22)
    at Receiver._write (/home/chuckyp/Desktop/datingapp/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:74:10)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:431:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:415:5)
    at Receiver.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:305:11)
    at Socket.socketOnData (/home/chuckyp/Desktop/datingapp/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:864:35)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
Emitted 'error' event on WebSocket instance at:
    at Receiver.receiverOnError (/home/chuckyp/Desktop/datingapp/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:769:13)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:108:12)
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:446:5)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:473:5)
    at Receiver.startLoop (/home/chuckyp/Desktop/datingapp/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:147:5)
    at Receiver._write (/home/chuckyp/Desktop/datingapp/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:74:10)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at Receiver.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:305:11) {
  [Symbol(status-code)]: 1002
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Heres the page that the error happens on. It doesn't happen immediately. It seems to happen when Im going to a component in the router with a '/' at the end. As in `localhost:3000/home` wont crash, but `localhost:3000/home/` will crash. `localhost:3000` wont crash but `localhost:3000/` will.  What's going on?

```
const Landing = () => {
    
    const [component, setComponent] = useState(<LoginCreate/>)

   
    return(
        <>
            <Background >
                <ComponentsContext.Provider value = {[component, setComponent]}>
                    {component}
                </ComponentsContext.Provider>
            </Background>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Webpack uses websockets for its hot module replacement, among other things. Could you include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that gives rise to this error?

Comment: @Tholle I added some more information to the question

Answer (score 1):

Changing a tag to Link element solved this problem in my case

Comment: do you mean changing the `a` tag?